# Scroll ListView in OnTouch method

Tags: c#, android, listview, onclick, xamarin

I am creating an application in xamarin studio and I have a problem with listview.
Default ListView working good, List is scrollable and I can go up and go down.

I created animation - I move finger to left - day is changing to yesterday and move to right, day is changing to tomorrow. When I made this animation, my listview isn't scrollable ;s I have this code:

```
public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
        {

            switch (e.Action)
            {
            case MotionEventActions.Down:
                _lastX = 0;
                _lastY = 0;
                _viewX = (int)e.GetX ();
                _viewY = (int)e.GetY ();
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Up:
                if (Math.Abs (_lastX) > 100) {
                    if (_lastX > 0) {
                        date = date.AddDays (-1);
                        DayList.Adapter = new HourInDayAdapter (this, hours, date);
                    } else {
                        date = date.AddDays (1);
                        DayList.Adapter = new HourInDayAdapter (this, hours, date);
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.MakeText (this, "text", ToastLength.Short).Show ();
                }
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Move:
                var left = (int)(e.RawX - _viewX);
                var down = (int)(e.RawY - _viewY);
                _lastY = down;
                _lastX = left;
                break;
            }

            return true;
        }
```

this is C#
I think, I should add some method to the MotionEventActions.Move but I don't know which method  ;s

Comment: No one knows the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what I would suggest is that you use a `GestureDetector` inside `OnTouch` this way you can "tell" when the item was swiped to either left or right. `GestureDetector` is a class that allows you to recognize certain patterns of motions.
You can inherit from one of the standard detectors like `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener`

i.e.

```
gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, YourGestureDetector);

public override bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
{
   if (gestureDetector.OnTouchEvent(e) && e.Action != MotionEventActions.Down)
   {
      //you have detected the gesture you were looking for
      //Do something about it
      return true; //because you want to notify that you handled the event so it won't propogare further (optional, depending on what behavior you want)   
   }
   return base.OnTouch(v, e);
}
```

Here is an example of an implementation of a detector:

```
class YourGestureDetector : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
    {
        //always return true in OnDown
        public override bool OnDown(MotionEvent e)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override bool OnScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY)
        {
           //detects scrolling motion. return true so it will be picked up by your detector
        }

        public override bool OnFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
        {
           //detects "swiping" motion. return true so it will be picked up by your detector
        }

    }
```

Comment: How can I create YourGestureDetector from some view? for example: LinearLayout? I haven't found this.

Comment: I'll edit the answer to contain an example of an implementation with the SimpleOnGestureListener. Read more about it in Android documentation but I think it should work in you case.

Comment: I know, but it's not resolve my problem.
I have: var _bg = FindViewById<LinearLayout> (Resource.Id.bg); and I need to detect gesture only here. I have read a lot and did not find

Comment: you set the on touch listener `var_bg.SetOnTouchListener(YourTouchListenerImplementation)`. Inside the implementation you use the code in the answer (because you'll have to implement onTouch. Hope you get it working eventually!

Comment: Yea, I did that. Thank you so much bro!

Answer (score 0):

No one knows the solution?

I did that:

```
case MotionEventActions.Move:


                var left = (int)(e.RawX - _viewX);
                var down2 = (int)(_lastY - e.GetY ());
                DayList.SmoothScrollBy (down2, 0);
                _lastY = (int)e.GetY();
                _lastX = left;
                break;
            }
```